# How to install printer-scaner drivers canon pixma ts8050 on ubuntu 16.04 32-bit from

Tags: 16.04

How to install canon pixma ts8050 printer-scaner drivers on ubuntu 16.04 32-bit 
from http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_ts_series/pixma-ts8050.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-1533040&os=Linux%20(32-bit)&language=EN

Comment: Have you tried this?
http://canon.supportprinters.net/2016/12/07/canon-ts8050-linux-driver-how-to-get-install/
Let us know how that worked please.

Comment: I think the link in @momist's comment is just a spam website.

Answer (score 1):

I have 64-bit version of ubuntu 16.04, but I guess following steps should work for you as well:

1. **Download packages from cannon pages** (dependent on version files **cnijfilter2**-5.40-1-deb.tar.gz and **scangearmp2**-3.40-1-deb.tar.gz or similar).
2. **Install printer**

   ```
   gunzip cnijfilter2-5.40-1-deb.tar.gz
   tar -xvf cnijfilter2-5.40-1-deb.tar
   cd cnijfilter2-5.40-1-deb
   ./install
   ```

   Then continue according to instructions in terminal (you will need also to administrator password).

   After this step new printer will appear in your printers and can be set as default.
3. **Install scanner application**

   ```
   gunzip scangearmp2-3.40-1-deb.tar.gz
   tar -xvf scangearmp2-3.40-1-deb.tar
   cd scangearmp2-3.40-1-deb
   ./install
   ```

   Then continue according to instructions in terminal (you will need also to administrator password).

   Run `scangearmp2` to scan image on your printer (works fine over network and USB).

Enjoy it ;-)